# How do I determine is my Capacitor + React app is running in development mode?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have a iOS/Android app on Capacitor.js and plain React.

Is there a way to detect in the React app whether the app is running in development mode (DEBUG flag on iOS) vs in production in a cross platform way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `Capacitor.DEBUG` value.

Comment: So simple! Works great.